# JWPlayer Mixed Source Playlist

Tags: javascript, jwplayer6

I am curious. Is it possible to create a playlist with "file: videofile.mp4" and "file: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234567" together, with JWPlayer?

I tried it, it creates a js error on the page. Searched for, and couldn't find a documentation about that. I wonder if anybody else tried and succeeded creating such a playlist.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you visit http://www.clipconverter.cc/ and download the said youtube video in mp4 format. it'll save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: The thing is, I am uploading all the local videos to youtube myself, in order to save some local space. So, that is not an option for me. I just want to know if that is possible. Thanks for the tip, though. Useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7zgZn/

Code:

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
   playlist: [{
          file:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRm04aUyOrM',
         title: "youtube",
    },
  {
         file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/HkauGhRi-640.mp4",
  image: "http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/HkauGhRi-640.jpg",
        title: "mp4",
    }],
      width: "80%",
     aspectratio: "16:9",
   stretching: 'exactfit',

});
```